# IIS Manager on Windows 11 not showing connections and no default website

Tags: windows, iis-10

Facts:

- Windows 11 Pro
- IIS is running (I can connect to my applications)
- IIS Manager shows nothing in the left panel (Connections), where localhost should be present.

There is no option to create/add new connection (is Windows 11, not server).

Tried several times to uninstall/reinstall from Windows features, no change.

Comment: Do you use any Malware protection software?

Comment: Yes (Malwarebytes), but I tried to disable it and reinstall everything. No luck...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after I installed MalwareBytes, and after enable IIS, it also goes wrong.

[image]

And then I disable MalwareBytes -->uninstall IIS --> restart PC -->disable MalwareBytes--> reinstall IIS. Features come back again.
[image]

There's conflict between MalwareBytes and IIS, you may consider uninstall Malwarebytes if using IIS frequently.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I have a different problem. I can't see anything (not even my pc) in the left tree.

Comment: @Adrian Did you try uninstall MalwareBytes and reinstall IIS after a restart